# Add custom sphinx extension like scipy.minimize

Tags: python, scipy, python-sphinx

[scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) has a nice interface with only one public function to perform minimization, and a lot of private functions for each method.

Looking at the source code, taking the Nelder-Mead method for instance, the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-neldermead.html#optimize-minimize-neldermead) of the method comes from this [private function](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/1bee17531da6cc2c9b49785bf4f9359e5d74b645/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L553-L779), but notice that the header (with the name of the function and the parameters) corresponds to the [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) function.

Looking at the [source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scipy/scipy/master/doc/source/optimize.minimize-neldermead.rst) of this page, it seems that they manage to do that with a custom Sphinx directive called `scipy-optimize:function:`.

My question is: **How can I find where they defined this directive?** I would like to do something very similar for a project of mine.

Edit: I found the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/doc/source/scipyoptdoc.py) for the definition of the directive.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/doc/source/scipyoptdoc.py).